# extract a subset dataframe from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big pandas dataframe. it has 8528 rows and 18287 columns.Each row is a sample, so the dataframe has 8528 samples and each samples has a label(infact, each row has a label). there are 4 types of labels(4 classes: A ,B ,C ,D).

I want to randomly extract 300 samples with 'A' labels , 300 samples with 'B' labels , 300 samples with 'C' labels and 300 samples with 'D' labels.

then put these 1200 samples with their labels  in a new pandas dataframe.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming dataframe variable name `df` and column name `label`. You can adjust to fit your names and code.

Pandas has a [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method that will select a random sample.

Another method [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) can be used to combine dataframes. The columns will be identical in the sampled dataframes since they come from the same original dataframe, so no additional arguments need to be specified.

```
a = df[df['label'] == 'A'].sample(n=300)
b = df[df['label'] == 'B'].sample(n=300)
c = df[df['label'] == 'C'].sample(n=300)
d = df[df['label'] == 'D'].sample(n=300)

combined = pd.concat([a,b,c,d])
```

Comment: Thanks a million. it was pretty helpful